# Scala: when multiple implicit conversions apply

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

The book "Programming in Scala" specifies:

> Up through Scala 2.7, that was the end of the story. Whenever multiple implicit conversions applied, the compiler refused to choose between
>   them. ... Scala 2.8 loosens this rule. If one of the available conversions is strictly
>   more speciﬁc than the others, then the compiler will choose the more speciﬁc
>   one. ... one implicit conversion is more speciﬁc than another
>   if one of the following applies:
>
> • The argument type of the former is a subtype of the latter’s.

Consider the following case:

```
object Encoder {
  implicit def fromInt(x: => Int) = { println("int"); new Encoder }
  implicit def fromIntArray(x: => Array[Int]) = { println("int array"); new Encoder }
  implicit def fromGenericArray[T](x: => Array[T])(implicit subencoder: (=> T) => Encoder) = {
    println("generic array")
    subencoder(x(0))
    new Encoder
  }
}
val e: Encoder = Array(1)
```

Multiple conversions can apply here, but it seems that fromIntArray is picked up. When fromIntArray is not present, fromGenericArray is chosen. My question is, is this specific case where the rule above applies so that can I safely expect that fromIntArray would apply for Array[Int] and fromGenericArray for all other Array[T]'s?

Comment: I would say yes, but read the Scala language specification, it goes to great lengths to explain implicit conflict resolution :-)

Comment: Looks like I'll have to. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

From the Scala language specification:

> If there are several eligible arguments which match the implicit
>   parameter’s type, a most speciﬁc one will be chosen using the rules of
>   static overloading resolution (§6.26.3). If the parameter has a
>   default argument and no implicit argument can be found the default
>   argument is used.

http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf